# Pulling URL with =importXM from the table

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Trying to get url from this link https://www.proz.com/profile/2900
There are also other urls, but I am interested only in this one:
[image]

I use the following:
=importXML(A1, "(//td[@class='sumContent']/a/@href)")

But as the result, I am getting the following results:
[image]

I would really appreciate it if you could help me extract only the url in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're using a class but trying to get a unique value out of it. We need some way of identifying the Website row. Here's one way to do it:

```
=VLOOKUP("Website",ImportXML(A1, "(//table[@id='standard_full']//tr)"),2,0)
```

### How it Works

1. The `ImportXML` dumps all the rows in the table of interest.
2. Then, use `VLOOKUP` to look for the row starting with "Website" (`0` gives us an exact match), and return the value in the 2nd column.